# Is there a method in jquery which repeats outputting and appending with multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to write a searchbar and want to have a dynamic amount of params for the search
Therefore I am trying to get jquery to firstly load the searchbar (in another file) and then clone it and append it to the body

I already tried changing serveral selectors but it doesnt work as expected

This is my jquery script

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#add").click(function(){
                $("#add_div").load("test.php");
            });
            $("#addbutton").click(function(){
                $("#add_div").clone().appendTo("body")
            });
        });
```

test.php contains the searchbar

The first load is running as expected (I get the searchbar once) but all clicks on the 'addbutton' (which is loaded with the searchbar) dont do anything

EDIT: fixed a small mistake

Comment: `$("addbutton")` is not a valid selector. I'm presuming you're missing a `.` or `#` prefix.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan for ponting out , did fix that but still no joy

Comment: If the 'addbutton' element added to the DOM in the `load()` call?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , yes it is

Comment: In which case you need to use a delegated event handler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks , that solved it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

the `$("addbutton")` selector must be wrong, it searches for the `addbutton` element which isn't a valid html element.